# Is there any way to disable Google slides' text recommendations while typing?

Tags: google-slides

This rage inducing.

When you type at nearly 100 wpm, it effectively operates as a subliminal speech smoother and brainwasher.

Is there any way to disable Google from this relentless AI-mind clubbing, and prevent it from flashing me with the continuous-bag-of-words prediction of what I will write?

It wasn't innovative when Shannon wrote about it in the 50s, it is more infuriating than Clippy the Destroyer of Performance, and it is incredibly difficult to google seeing as it must be a "smart" feature, but "smart" is in front of everything in the google namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Disable:

```
Tools > Preferences > Smart Compose
```

From the Google Slides ribbon.